# The application can't connect with a solr engine on a different computer

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I run my Solr engine on Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox. The guest operating system is connect to local network. It has this IP address: 192.168.10.102.

I'm trying to connect with Solr engine using my browser. I'm going to http://192.168.10.102:8983/solr/ and everything is works.

I wrote an application in Java (with SolrJ). I try to connect to the Solr engine and delete everything. The code looks like this:

```
server = new HttpSolrServer("http://192.168.10.102:8983/solr/");
server.deleteByQuery("*:*");
server.commit();
```

Sadly I get an exception:

> [main] INFO org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil -
>   Creating new http client,
>   config:maxConnections=128&maxConnectionsPerHost=32&followRedirects=false
>   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   Server at http://192.168.10.102:8983/solr returned non ok status:404,
>   message:Not Found     at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:372)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.deleteByQuery(SolrServer.java:285)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.deleteByQuery(SolrServer.java:271)
>
> ...

Everything is good when I comment *deleteByQuery()* and *commit()* functions.

How can I solve it?

Comment: does your schema.xml has unique field mentioned?You need to have a uniqueKey-field in your schema. like this <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

Comment: could you share the schema.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create any collection your url should look like http://192.168.10.102:8983/solr/collection1 and then you can try do something